# How to change selected text in FabricJS IText object?

Tags: fabricjs

Is there any way to change a selected text?

Assume I have a text "***Sample Text***" and programmatically select a word **Sample**

```
...
text.selectionStart = 0;
text.selectionEnd = 6;
...
```

So, text.getSelectedText() returns *Sample*, which is what I need...
Next step, what I want is to change it to any other text.

Generally speaking, I want to change a text which is between *selectionStart* and *selectionEnd*.

Any ideas?
Tnx in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
canvas.setHeight(300);
canvas.setWidth(500);
var text = new fabric.IText('Sample Text', {
   left: 50,
   top: 100,
   fontFamily: 'arial',
   fill: '#333',
   fontSize: 50
 });
canvas.add(text);
function replaceText(){
 var res = text.getSelectedText();
 text.insertChars(res.split('').sort(() => Math.random() * 2 - 1).join(''));//adding shuffled string
 text.selectionStart = 0;
 text.selectionEnd = 6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.19/fabric.js"></script>
<button onclick="replaceText()">Replace</button>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

You can use `insertChars()` method of IText.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
Just curious, what you would do if you need to replace text in two different locations of the sentence at the same time? Text that needs to be replaced could be different...

Comment: Select range and set one by one.

Comment: Since I've changed first text the coordinates of the second one will shift.
Location 10, for example, will move to 15, but I don't have it... I have only 10...

Comment: If you don't want to preserve char style, you can change whole text.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158181/discussion-between-eugene-vilder-and-durga).